# Apache load balancer didn't failover to hot spares

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy

Found that our Apache load balancer didn't failover to the hot spares when the primary server's application was responding with a 500 error.

This is how we had the proxy setup

```
   <Proxy balancer://hotspare>

        BalancerMember ajp://node1:8463 loadfactor=100 retry=30
        BalancerMember ajp://node2:8463 status=+H retry=0
        BalancerMember ajp://node3:8463 status=+H retry=0

        ProxySet lbmethod=bytraffic
   </Proxy>
```

It only actually failed over when node1 was shutdown.
Can anyone explain this behavour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to failover in case the backend server returns an HTTP error code (e.g. 500), you have to work with the "`failonstatus`" option.

Reference can be found here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass

> failonstatus  -   A single or comma-separated list of HTTP status
>   codes. If set this will force the worker into error state when the
>   backend returns any status code in the list. Worker recovery behaves
>   the same as other worker errors. Available with Apache HTTP Server
>   2.2.17 and later.

Otherwise there will only be a failover if the backend doesn't respond at all (like you already mentioned).